# Read/Write Mysql DB using Python API

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, boto, rds

Is there any Python API that will allow me to interact with a remote MySQL db (running on RDS) in a transactional manner (read, write)? I believe this can be done using Boto for DynamoDB but I couldn't find anything similar for MySQL.
Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Bucho

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing in Boto,
The easiest and simplest library to interact with MySQL using python in my opinion is [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).